# rsync only certain types of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I know there has been a huge discussion about this but I have not found something this specific. 
Im trying to copy all *.key files in /home/*/ directory

This does not work

```
/usr/bin/rsync -auPA --include="*/*.key" --exclude="*" /home/* /tmp/test
```

This works but it copies over unwanted empty directories like /home/uname/Documents

```
/usr/bin/rsync -auPA --include="*/" --include="*.key" --exclude="*" /home /tmp/test
```

Basically what i need for rsync to do is to copy only files with .key extension and only create necessarily folders that contain .key files

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `-m` option. From the man page:

```
-m, --prune-empty-dirs
          This option tells the receiving rsync to get rid of empty directories from the file-list, including  nested  directories  that
          have  no  non-directory children.  This is useful for avoiding the creation of a bunch of useless directories when the sending
          rsync is recursively scanning a hierarchy of files using include/exclude/filter rules.

          Note that the use of transfer rules, such as the --min-size option, does not affect what goes into the  file  list,  and  thus
          does not leave directories empty, even if none of the files in a directory match the transfer rule.

          Because the file-list is actually being pruned, this option also affects what directories get deleted when a delete is active.
          However, keep in mind that excluded files and directories can prevent existing items from being deleted due to an exclude both
          hiding source files and protecting destination files.  See the perishable filter-rule option for how to avoid this.

          You can prevent the pruning of certain empty directories from the file-list by using a global "protect" filter.  For instance,
          this option would ensure that the directory "emptydir" was kept in the file-list:

          --filter ’protect emptydir/’


          Here’s an example that copies all .pdf files in a hierarchy, only creating the necessary destination directories to  hold  the
          .pdf  files,  and  ensures  that any superfluous files and directories in the destination are removed (note the hide filter of
          non-directories being used instead of an exclude):

          rsync -avm --del --include=’*.pdf’ -f ’hide,! */’ src/ dest


          If you didn’t want to remove superfluous destination files, the more time-honored options  of  "--include='*/'  --exclude='*'"
          would work fine in place of the hide-filter (if that is more natural to you).
```